# Imprimir cadena de texto n cantidad de veces

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

tengo una duda, como podría imprimir una frase "N" cantidad de veces, siendo el usuario el que ingresa el numero de veces que se deben imprimir.

Que ciclo me recomendarían utilizar para este proceso?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya sabes que con `var numero = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un numero por favor: "));` puedes obtener un numero, verdad?

Ahora podrias usar un bucle [for](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) para repetir el numero de veces que el usuario ingrese el mismo código, que en este caso seria imprimir un texto.

La sintaxis del bucle `for` es `for ({contador}; {condición_para_seguir_ejecutando}; {aumento_al_contador}) { // Código }`

En el ejemplo de abajo, el `{contador}` es una variable con un valor de 0: `let i =0;`, la `{condición_para_seguir_ejecutando}` es `i < numero` donde i es el contador y numero es el numero que el usuario ingreso, esta condición se asegura de que no se haya imprimido en consola mas veces que la que el usuario desea, y finalmente, al terminar todo el código dentro del bucle, aumentamos en 1 al contador con `i++;`.

Y el `código` es `console.log('Texto a imprimir');` que es la función que imprime en la consola.

#### Ejemplo (Ejecutable):

```js
var numero = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un numero por favor: "));

for (let i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
  console.log('Texto a imprimir');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

puedes realizarlo de la siguiente manera.

```js
const userCounter = 10;

const wordsRepeat = Array(userCounter).fill('N');

console.log(wordsRepeat);
```

Saludos!